# How to allow insertion of the internal images in MediaWiki?

Tags: image, mediawiki, src

Allow img tag to be used in wikitext.

```
$wgAllowImageTag = true;
```

This variant works

```
<IMG SRC = "http://picasa.google.com/images/thumb_edit.png">
```

Cuts the src attribute for images from my site.

```
<IMG SRC = "http://mysite.com/img.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

in tinymce add

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host: false,
```